# Is there a function in Python to list the attributes and methods of a particular object?

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python to list the attributes and methods of a particular object?

Something like:

```
ShowAttributes ( myObject )

   -> .count
   -> .size

ShowMethods ( myObject )

   -> len
   -> parse
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546337/how-do-i-perform-introspection-on-an-object-in-python-2-x

Comment: And this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a

Comment: [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) is a name given to a different concept in python. the term `attribute` would suit you better. an in-depth reading that I like, about both is http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You want to look at the [`dir()`](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/built_in_functions.html) function:

```
>>> li = []
>>> dir(li)      
['append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert',
'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

> `li` is a list, so `dir(li)` returns a list of all the methods of a list. Note that the returned list contains the names of the methods as strings, not the methods themselves.

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

No this will show all inherited methods as well. Consider this example:

**test.py:**

```
class Foo:
    def foo(): pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(): pass
```

**Python interpreter:**

```
>>> from test import Foo, Bar
>>> dir(Foo)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'foo']
>>> dir(Bar)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'bar', 'foo']
```

---

**You should note that** [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) states:

> **Note:** Because `dir()`  is supplied
>   *primarily as a convenience for use at
>   an interactive prompt*, it tries to
>   supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a
>   rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, *and its detailed behavior
>   may change across releases*. For
>   example, metaclass attributes are not
>   in the result list when the argument
>   is a class.

Therefore it's not safe to use in your code. Use `vars()` instead. `Vars()` doesn't include information about the superclasses, you'd have to collect them yourself.

---

If you're using `dir()` to find information in an interactive interpreter, consider the use of `help()`.

Comment: Also this just lists the methods directly applicable to this object type, not its parent class or parent's parent class, right?

Comment: Thanks again, but does it also print properties of an object?

Answer (score 12):

Don't dir() and vars() suit you?

Comment: Everybody must read this http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html right after reading the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 11):

and for a more human-readable way, you can use [see](http://github.com/inky/see/tree/master):

```
In [1]: from see import see
In [2]: x = "hello world!"
In [3]: see(x)
Out[3]: 
  []   in   +   *   %   <   <=   ==   !=   >   >=   hash()   help()   len()
  repr()   str()   .capitalize()   .center()   .count()   .decode()
  .encode()   .endswith()   .expandtabs()   .find()   .format()   .index()
  .isalnum()   .isalpha()   .isdigit()   .islower()   .isspace()   .istitle()
  .isupper()   .join()   .ljust()   .lower()   .lstrip()   .partition()
  .replace()   .rfind()   .rindex()   .rjust()   .rpartition()   .rsplit()
  .rstrip()   .split()   .splitlines()   .startswith()   .strip()
  .swapcase()   .title()   .translate()   .upper()   .zfill()
```

Comment: superb! one thing I miss is that you cannot get `help()` or `__doc__` for a thing like `<=`, so you should know what you are doing already, regarding operators. well, if you don't know their magic methods from head. :) altogether a minor issue and a superb package!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is with the nifty [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) environment. It lets you tab complete to find all the methods and fields of an object.

Answer (score -1):

It is surprising to me that no one mentioned the python object function:
  `keys()`

Comment: `keys()` is not a builtin function in python. You can call `.keys()` on a dict, but it doesn't meet OP's needs.